# c++: The variable 'n' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void citire(float a[][20], int *m, int *n)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("nr linii="); scanf("%d", m);
    printf("nr linii="); scanf("%d", n);
    for (i = 0; i<*m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<*n; j++)
        {
            printf("a(%d,%d)=", i, j);
            scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
        }
}
int main()
{
    float b[20][20];
    int *m, *n;
    citire(b, m, n);
    getch();
}
```

i have an error: The variable 'n' is being used without being initialized. i also tried to remove the "*" please help !
how do i fix it?

Comment: If you are indeed using `C++` and not `C` (which is what this code looks like) you should start using `C++` features like `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::string`, etc.

Comment: _"how do i fix it?"_ Initialize the variable.

Comment: `m` and `n` are *uninitialized pointers*, and dereferencing them is undefined behavior. You are also using a very "c"ish style.

Comment: i know that i can use it but it dosen't fix my problem

Comment: You need to declare m and n as normal int variables and put tehm a value, for example `int m=30, n=50;`, then call  `citire(b, &m, &n);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because you declared m and n as pointers , thus you need to allocate space for them prior to using.

For what you want, you need to change your read function to take references as parameters,and you can declare m and n as normal ints :

```
int m, n
void citire(float a[][20],int& m, int& n);
```

Comment: You don't have to allocate space, but they must point to *something* :)

Comment: True, but considering OP's question, I would rather just give him this mnemonic then explaining what pointers are and what they are used for.

Answer (score 2):

> The variable 'n' is being used without being initialized. how do i fix it?

You initialize the variable.

```
int *m = new int;
int *n = new int;
citire(b, m, n);
delete m;
delete n;
```

But probably you want it to be way simpler:

```
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
citire(b, &m, &n);
```

Or maybe, you don't even need them at all:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void citire(float a[][20])
{
    int i, j;
    int m, n;
    printf("nr linii="); scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("nr linii="); scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i<m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("a(%d,%d)=", i, j);
            scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    float b[20][20];
    citire(b);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", n);
```

You are not allocating memory for `n`. You should allocate the memory in caller and then pass that pointer to this function .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you create the a pointer outside of the function then pass it in....

But you are filling the value of the pointer, not what the pointer is pointing to.  In fact you never allocated memory for `n`.  `n` needs to point to valid memory and then needs to be filled in

Also are you really using C++?  If so why you are using `scanf`?  You should be using streams